# Linux unzip to a pipe and grep filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe, unzip

I have a bash script in which I am looping through a group of zipped filenames, and inside the loop unzipping each zipped file to a pipe and grepping filenames of a certain pattern from the unzipped files. Something like:

```
while read line
do
  matched=$((unzip -p $line | grep $regex))
  ...
done << "$zipfilelist"
```

My worry is if this is a very efficient way of doing it, considering cases where unzipping of a zipped file causes a large list of sub(files/directories) which is pushed to a pipe( memory). Is there a more efficient way to handle this.

Comment: The pipe has a limited size. (I've seen 128 KiB.) The writer will block if it fills up. The reader will block if it becomes empty.

Comment: That's probably the best approach.

Comment: [zipgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zipgrep) is worth a try perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of `zgrep`? You can use a regular expression on a group of zipped files, only using that one command. Just check `man zgrep` for more information.

Comment: `zgrep` reads `gzip` compressed files, not zip archives.